# Conteo de apariciones y caracteres sucesivos en un string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Busco resolver un problema de manejo de strings en python cuyo string es un conjunto de caracteres separados por coma. Como parte del problema debo obtener dos cosas en la salida:

- La primera es la sucesión de caracteres que conforman la contraseña sin repeticiones, en mayúscula y separadas por espacio.
- La cantidad de veces que se repitió cada carácter de la contraseña de manera consecutiva, separado también por espacio.

Tengo la siguiente entrada ejemplo:

```
'E,E,e,E,E,d,E,E,D,c,C,E,E,B,E,E,a,E,A,E,g,E,G,E,f,E'
```

Debo obtener como salida lo siguiente:

```
E D E D C E B E A E A E G E G E F E

5 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Hasta ahora he intentado lo siguiente:

```
abecedario=['A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e','F','f','G','g']
resultado=[]
letras=[]
cont=[]
contA=0
contB=0
contC=0
contD=0
contE=0
contF=0
contG=0
j=0

entrada=input('')

for i in range(len(entrada)):
    resultado.append(i*0)
    letras.append(i*0)
    cont.append(i*0)


for i in range(len(entrada)):

    if 'A'==entrada[i] or 'a'==entrada[i]:
        contA=contA+1
    
    if contA==1:
        print('A', end=" ")
        contB=0
        contC=0
        contD=0
        contF=0
        contG=0
        contH=0
        contI=0
        contE=0
        

if 'B'==entrada[i] or 'b'==entrada[i]:
    contB=contB+1
    if contB==1:
        print('B', end=" ")
        contA=0
        contC=0
        contD=0
        contE=0
        contF=0
        contG=0
        

if 'C'==entrada[i] or entrada[i]=='c':
    contC=contC+1
    if contC==1:
        print('C', end=" ")
        contA=0
        contB=0
        contD=0
        contE=0
        contF=0
        contG=0        

if entrada[i]=='D' or entrada[i]=='d':
    contD=contD+1
    if contD==1:
        print('D', end=" ")
        contA=0
        contB=0
        contC=0
        contE=0
        contF=0
        contG=0

if entrada[i]=='E' or entrada[i]=='e':
    contE=contE+1
    if contE==1:
        print('E', end=" ")
        contA=0
        contB=0
        contC=0
        contD=0
        contF=0
        contG=0

if entrada[i]=='F' or entrada[i]=='f':
    contF=contF+1
    if contF==1:
        print('F', end=" ")
        contB=0
        contC=0
        contD=0
        contA=0
        contG=0
        contE=0

if entrada[i]=='G' or entrada[i]=='g':
    contG=contG+1
    if contG==1:
        print('G',end=" ")
        contA=0
        contB=0
        contC=0
        contD=0
        contE=0
        contF=0
```

Es lo que llevo por ahora, aún no logro que cuente los caracteres

Comment: Y que has intentado? Aquí no se hacen tareas/trabajos. Si quieres que te ayudemos debes de colocar lo que has intentado. Recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/534141/edit) tu pregunta cuantas veces quieras para así mejorarla.

Comment: Gracias Christian

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente, separa los caracteres de la entrada y conviertélos a mayúsculas:

```
mayusculas = [letra.upper() for letra in entrada.split(",")]
```

Luego crea dos listas, una que almacenará las letras sin repetición y otra que contendrá el número de repeticiones. Para llenarlas, itera en la lista de mayúsculas siguiendo las siguientes condiciones:

- Si el elemento actual es igual al anterior, incrementa el contador de repeticiones
- Si el elemento actual NO es igual al anterior, agrega el elemento nuevo a la lista e inicializa el contador de repeticiones a 1.

El código completo quedaría:

```
entrada = "E,E,e,E,E,d,E,E,D,c,C,E,E,B,E,E,a,E,A,E,g,E,G,E,f,E"

mayusculas = [letra.upper() for letra in entrada.split(",")]

letras_unicas = [mayusculas[0]]
repeticiones = [1]

for i in range(1, len(mayusculas)):
    if mayusculas[i] == mayusculas[i - 1]:
        repeticiones[-1] += 1
    else:
        letras_unicas.append(mayusculas[i])
        repeticiones.append(1)

print(" ".join(letras_unicas))
print(" ".join(str(x) for x in repeticiones))
```

Y la salida en consola, que puedes [ejecutar online](https://www.online-python.com/yYLSm2g4kp) es:

```
E D E D C E B E A E A E G E G E F E
5 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```